# call python function from skin xml on kodi

Tags: kodi

i need to create an addon for kodi, that will change its appearance, install a default addon and ask for username and password for that addon.

create a button in home.xml and try to call a function from a python file but nothing happens.

To create the addon, I am following the Kodi guide a lot https://kodi.wiki/view/Skinning_Manual The first thing I did after installing Kodi on my Windows 10 PC was to go to the installation folder and copy the skin.estuary folder, which is the default skin of kodi, I am taking this as the base for my skin, then in the addon.xml file I added the line <import addon="script.scriptParaSkin" version="1.0.0" / > the content of the file is this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<addon id="skin.ivanjrch" version="1.0.0" name="ivanjrch" provider-name="Ivan">
    <requires>
        <import addon="xbmc.gui"                   version="5.16.0"/>
        <import addon="xbmc.python"                version="3.0.0" />
        <import addon="script.scriptParaSkin" version="1.0.0" />
    </requires>
    <extension point="xbmc.gui.skin" debugging="false">
        <res width="1920" height="1440" aspect="4:3" default="false" folder="xml" />
        <res width="1920" height="1280" aspect="3:2" default="false" folder="xml" />
        <res width="1920" height="1200" aspect="16:10" default="false" folder="xml" />
        <res width="2040" height="1080" aspect="17:9" default="false" folder="xml" />
        <res width="1920" height="1080" aspect="16:9" default="true" folder="xml" />
        <res width="2560" height="1080" aspect="21:9" default="false" folder="xml" />
        <res width="2338" height="1080" aspect="19.5:9" default="false" folder="xml" />
        <res width="2160" height="1080" aspect="18:9" default="false" folder="xml" />
    </extension>
    <extension point="xbmc.python.library" library="default.py">
        <provides>executable</provides>
    </extension>
    <extension point="xbmc.addon.metadata">
        <platform>all</platform>
        <license>CC BY-SA 4.0, GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE Version 2.0</license>
        <forum>http://forum.kodi.tv/</forum>
        <source>https://github.com/xbmc/skin.estuary/</source>
        <assets>
            <icon>resources/icon.png</icon>
            <fanart>resources/fanart.jpg</fanart>
            <screenshot>resources/screenshot-01.jpg</screenshot>
            <screenshot>resources/screenshot-02.jpg</screenshot>
            <screenshot>resources/screenshot-03.jpg</screenshot>
            <screenshot>resources/screenshot-04.jpg</screenshot>
            <screenshot>resources/screenshot-05.jpg</screenshot>
            <screenshot>resources/screenshot-06.jpg</screenshot>
            <screenshot>resources/screenshot-07.jpg</screenshot>
            <screenshot>resources/screenshot-08.jpg</screenshot>
        </assets>
        <summary lang="af_ZA">Estuary oortreksel deur phil65. (Kodi se bestek oortreksel)</summary>
        <summary lang="ar_SA">مظهر Estuary بواسطة phil65. ( مظهر كودي الافتراضي )</summary>
        <summary lang="be_BY">Абалонка &quot;Estuary&quot; ад phil65. (прадвызначаная абалонка Kodi)</summary>
        <summary lang="bg_BG">Estuary облик от phil65 и Piers. (стандартния облик на Kodi)</summary>
        <summary lang="ca_ES">Aparença Estuary per phil65 i Piers. (aparença predeterminada de Kodi)</summary>
        <summary lang="cs_CZ">Vzhled Estuary od autora phil65. (Výchozí vzhled Kodi)</summary>
        <summary lang="da_DK">Estuary skin af phil65 (Kodis standard brugerflade)</summary>
        <summary lang="de_DE">Estuary Skin von phil65. (Kodi-Standardskin)</summary>
        <summary lang="el_GR">Το κέλυφος Estuary από τον phil65 και τον Pier. (προεπιλεγμένο κέλυφος του Kodi)</summary>
        <summary lang="en_GB">Estuary skin by phil65. (Kodi&apos;s default skin)</summary>
        <summary lang="en_NZ">Estuary skin by phil65 and Piers. (Kodi&apos;s default skin)</summary>
        <summary lang="en_US">Estuary skin by phil65 and Piers. (Kodi&apos;s default skin)</summary>
        <summary lang="es_AR">Skin Estuary por phil65 (skin por defecto de Kodi)</summary>
        <summary lang="es_ES">Skin Estuary, creado por phil65 and Piers (skin por defecto de Kodi).</summary>
        <summary lang="es_MX">Máscara Estuary por phil65 y Piers. (La máscara predeterminada de Kodi)</summary>
        <summary lang="et_EE">Estuary rüü autor on phil65. (Kodi vaikerüü)</summary>
        <summary lang="eu_ES">Estuary azala phil65-ek egina. (Kodiren azal lehenetsia)</summary>
        <summary lang="fa_IR">پوستهٔ اسچوری به دست phil65. (پوستهٔ پیش‌گزیدهٔ کودی)</summary>
        <summary lang="fi_FI">Estuary-ulkoasun ovat kehittäneet phil65 ja Piers. (Kodin oletusulkoasu)</summary>
        <summary lang="fr_CA">Habillage Estuary par phil65 et Piers (habillage par défaut de Kodi).</summary>
        <summary lang="fr_FR">Estuary, un habillage par phil65 et Piers (habillage d&apos;origine de Kodi)</summary>
        <summary lang="gl_ES">Pel Estuary por phil65 and Piers. (Pel predefinida do Kodi)</summary>
        <summary lang="he_IL">מעטפת Estuary של phil65 (ברירת המחדל של קודי)</summary>
        <summary lang="hr_HR">Estuary presvlaka autora phil65 i Piersa. (Zadana Kodi presvlaka)</summary>
        <summary lang="hu_HU">Estuary felszín. Készítette phil65 és Piers. (Kodi alapértelmezett felszín)</summary>
        <summary lang="id_ID">Skin Estuary oleh phil65. (Skin default Kodi)</summary>
        <summary lang="is_IS">Estuary-skinnið eftir phil65. (sjálfgefið útlit Kodi)</summary>
        <summary lang="it_IT">Skin Estuary di phil65. (Skin predefinita di Kodi)</summary>
        <summary lang="ja_JP">Estuaryスキン by phil65 and Piers (Kodi デフォルトスキン)</summary>
        <summary lang="ko_KR">phil65가 만든 Estuary 스킨. (Kodi 기본 스킨)</summary>
        <summary lang="lt_LT">Estuary teminė išvaizda, kurią sukūrė phil65 ir Piers. (Numatytoji Kodi teminė išvaizda)</summary>
        <summary lang="lv_LV">Estuary apvalks no phil65. (Kodi noklusējuma apvalks)</summary>
        <summary lang="mk_MK">Estuary skin by phil65. (Kodi&apos;s default skin)</summary>
        <summary lang="ms_MY">Kulit Estuary oleh phil65 dan rakan-rakan. (Kulit lalai Kodi)</summary>
        <summary lang="nb_NO">Esturay-drakt av phil65 og Piers. (Kodis forvalgte drakt)</summary>
        <summary lang="nl_NL">Estuary skin door phil65 en Piers. (Kodi&apos;s standaardskin)</summary>
        <summary lang="pl_PL">Skóra Eustary autorstwa phil65. (domyślna skóra Kodi)</summary>
        <summary lang="pt_BR">Skin Estuary por phil65 e Piers. (Skin padrão do Kodi)</summary>
        <summary lang="pt_PT">Visual Estuary de phil65 e Piers. (Visual por omissão do Kodi)</summary>
        <summary lang="ro_RO">Tema Estuary de phil65. (Temă implicită pentru Kodi)</summary>
        <summary lang="ru_RU">Обложка Estuary от phil65 (стандартная обложка Kodi)</summary>
        <summary lang="sk_SK">Vzhľad Estuary, vytvorili phil65. (predvolený vzhľad pre Kodi)</summary>
        <summary lang="sr_RS">Маска Estuary аутора phil65 и Piers. (Подразумевана Коди маска)</summary>
        <summary lang="sr_RS@latin">Maska Estuary autora phil65 i Piers. (Podrazumevana Kodi maska)</summary>
        <summary lang="sv_SE">Estuary, ett skal av phil65. (Kodi&apos;s standardskal)</summary>
        <summary lang="szl">Skōra Estuary ôd phil65 i Piers. (Wychodnŏ skōra Kodi)</summary>
        <summary lang="th_TH">สกิน Estuary โดย phil65 และ Piers (หน้าตาเริ่มต้นของKodi)</summary>
        <summary lang="tr_TR">Estuary dış görünümü. phil65 (Kodi&apos;nin varsayılan dış görünümü)</summary>
        <summary lang="uk_UA">Обкладинка Estuary від phil65 і Piers. (стандартна обкладинка Kodi)</summary>
        <summary lang="vi_VN">Giao diện Estuary của phil65. (Giao diện mặc định của Kodi)</summary>
        <summary lang="zh_CN">phil65 开发的 Estuary 皮肤（Kodi 的默认皮肤）。</summary>
        <summary lang="zh_TW">phil65與Piers 製作的Estuary佈景主題（Kodi的預設佈景主題）</summary>
        <description lang="af_ZA">Estuary is die bestek oortreksel vir Kodi 17.0 en op. Dit poog om maklik te wees vir eerste keer Kodi gebruikers om te verstaan en te gebruik.</description>
        <description lang="ar_SA">Estuary هو المظهر الافتراضي ل كودي الإصدار 17.0 و أعلى. يطمح بأن يكون سهل الاستخدام والفهم لمستخدمين كودي الجدد.</description>
        <description lang="be_BY">Estuary - прадвызначаная абалонка для Kodi 17.0 і пазнейшых версій. Яна будзе простай і зразумелай для карыстальнікаў, якія не мелі досведу працы з Kodi.</description>
        <description lang="bg_BG">Estuary е стандартният облик на Kodi 17 и по-новите версии. Целта е да се улеснят хората, които се сблъскват за първи път с Kodi.</description>
        <description lang="ca_ES">Estuary és l&apos;aparença predeterminada de Kodi 17.0 i posteriors. Per als usuaris per primera vegada de Kodi, intenta ser fàcil d&apos;entendre i d&apos;utilitzar.</description>
        <description lang="cs_CZ">Estuary je výchozí vzhled pro Kodi 17.0 a vyšší. Snaží se být jednoduše pochopitelný a použitelný pro nové uživatele Kodi.</description>
        <description lang="da_DK">Estuary er standardbrugerfladen for Kodi 17.0 og højere. Det forenkler førstegangsbrugen af Kodi ved at gøre det nemmere at forstå og bruge.</description>
        <description lang="de_DE">Estuary ist der Standardskin für Kodi 17.0 und höher. Ziel war es, einen einfach zu bedienenden Skin für neue Kodi-Benutzer zu entwickeln.</description>
        <description lang="el_GR">Το Estuary είναι η προεπιλεγμένη αμφίεση για τις εκδόσεις Kodi 17.0 και άνω. Επιχειρεί να είναι προσιτό στους αρχάριους χρήστες του Kodi για να το κατανοήσουν και να το χρησιμοποιήσουν.</description>
        <description lang="en_GB">Estuary is the default skin for Kodi 17.0 and above. It attempts to be easy for first time Kodi users to understand and use.</description>
        <description lang="en_NZ">Estuary is the default skin for Kodi 17.0 and above. It attempts to be easy for first time Kodi users to understand and use.</description>
        <description lang="en_US">Estuary is the default skin for Kodi 17.0 and above. It attempts to be easy for first time Kodi users to understand and use.</description>
        <description lang="es_AR">Estuary es el skin por defecto para Kodi 17.0 y posteriores. Intenta ser fácil de entender y utilizar para los usuarios Kodi primerizos.</description>
        <description lang="es_ES">Estuary es el skin por defecto para Kodi 17.0 o superior. Su objetivo es la facilidad de comprensión y uso para usuarios primerizos de Kodi.</description>
        <description lang="es_MX">Estuary es la máscara por defecto para Kodi 17.0 y superior. Su objetivo es ser fácil de entender y usar para los usuarios nuevos a Kodi.</description>
        <description lang="et_EE">Estuary on Kodi vaikerüü versioonist 17.0. Kodi esmakasutajatel on rüüd kerge mõista ja kasutada.</description>
        <description lang="eu_ES">Estuary azala kodi 17.0 eta berriagoen azal lehenetsia da. Kodiren erabiltzaile hasiberrientzako erabilerraza eta ulerterraza izaten saiatzen da.</description>
        <description lang="fa_IR">اسچوری پوستهٔ پیش‌گزیدهٔ کودی ۱۷٫۰ و بالاتر است. این پوسته تلاش می‌کند درک و استفاده‌اش برای کاربرانی که نخستین بار با کودی کار می‌کنند، ساده باشد.</description>
        <description lang="fi_FI">Estuary on Kodin oletusulkoasu alkaen versiosta 17.0. Sen on tarkoitus olla uusille Kodi-käyttäjille selkeä ja helppokäyttöinen.</description>
        <description lang="fr_CA">Estuary est l’habillage par défaut pour Kodi 17.0 et ultérieure. Il s’efforce d’être facile à comprendre et à utiliser pour les utilisateurs débutants de Kodi.</description>
        <description lang="fr_FR">Estuary est l&apos;habillage d&apos;origine pour Kodi 17.0 et supérieur. Il est facile à comprendre et à utiliser pour les utilisateurs novices de Kodi.</description>
        <description lang="gl_ES">Estuary é a pel predefinida para Kodi 17.0 e superior. Esta tenta ser doada de entender e usar polos usuarios recen chegados a Kodi.</description>
        <description lang="he_IL">Estuary היא מעטפת ברירת המחדל של קודי מגרסאות 17.0 ומעלה. מטרת מעטפת זו היא להיות פשוטה לשימוש ולהכרה ראשונית על ידי משתמשים חדשים.</description>
        <description lang="hr_HR">Estuary je zadana presvlaka za Kodi 17.0 i novije inačice. To je pokušaj da se novim korisnicima olakša prvo korištenje i kasnija upotreba Kodija.</description>
        <description lang="hu_HU">Az Estuary az alapértelmezett felszín a 17.0 és újabb Kodi kiadásokban. Megpróbál könnyen kezelhető és használható lenni, az újonc Kodi felhasználóknak is.</description>
        <description lang="id_ID">Estuary adalah skin default untuk Kodi 17.0 dan di atasnya. Ini untuk mudah dipahami dan digunakan oleh pengguna Kodi yang pertama kali.</description>
        <description lang="is_IS">Estuary er sjálfgefið skinn fyrir Kodi 17.0 og nýrri. Með því á að vera auðvelt fyrir fyrsta-skiptis Kodi-notendur að skilja og nota viðmótið.</description>
        <description lang="it_IT">Estuary è la skin predefinita di Kodi 17.0 e successivi. Cerca di essere facile da capire e da usare per chi si avvicina per la prima volta a Kodi.</description>
        <description lang="ja_JP">EstuaryはKodi 17.0およびそれ以上のバージョンで標準のスキンです。ユーザーが初めてKodiに触れる際にわかりやすく使えるようにしてあります。</description>
        <description lang="ko_KR">Estuary는 Kodi 17.0이상의 기본 스킨입니다. 처음 Kodi를 접하는 사용자가 쉽게 이해하고 사용할 수 있도록 만들었습니다.</description>
        <description lang="lt_LT">Estuary yra numatytoji Kodi 17.0 ir aukštesnių versijų teminė išvaizda. Jos tikslas yra būti lengvai perprantama naujiems Kodi vartotojams.</description>
        <description lang="ms_MY">Estuary ialah kulit lalai untuk Kodi 17.0 dan ke atas. Kulit yang mudah digunakan buat pengguna Kodi kali pertama untuk memahami dan menggunakannya.</description>
        <description lang="nb_NO">Estuary er forvalgt drakt til Kodi 17.0 og nyere. Det tar mål av seg å være en enkel drakt for førstegangsbrukere av Kodi, slik at det er til å forstå og kan brukes.</description>
        <description lang="nl_NL">Estuary is de standaardskin voor Kodi 17.0 en hoger. Het tracht eenvoudig te begrijpen en te gebruiken te zijn voor beginnende Kodi-gebruikers.</description>
        <description lang="pl_PL">Eustary jest domyślną skórą Kodi dla wersji 17.0 i późniejszych. Jest próbą łatwego wprowadzenia początkujących użytkowników w funkcje Kodi.</description>
        <description lang="pt_BR">Estuary é a skin padrão para o Kodi 17.0 e acima. Objetiva ser fácil para usuários que iniciam no Kodi pela primeira vez, facilitando aprendizagem de uso do mesmo.</description>
        <description lang="pt_PT">O Estuary é o visual por omissão para o Kodi 17.0 e posteriores. Tenta ser simples para os utilizadores menos experientes do Kodi compreenderem e usarem.</description>
        <description lang="ro_RO">Estuary este tema implicită pentru Kodi 17.0 și versiunile ulterioare. Încearcă să fie ușor de înțeles și folosit pentru utilizatorii care folosesc Kodi pentru prima dată.</description>
        <description lang="ru_RU">Estuary — это стандартная обложка Kodi, начиная с версии 17.0. Простая и понятная в использовании для новых пользователей Kodi.</description>
        <description lang="sk_SK">Estuary je predvolený vzhľad pre Kodi 17.0 a vyššie. Je výsledkom snahy o vzhľad, ktorý bude ľahko zrozumiteľný a použiteľný pre nových používateľov Kodi.</description>
        <description lang="sr_RS">Estuary је подразумевана маска за Kodi 17.0 и изнад. Покушава да буде једноставан за разумевање и коришћење новим корисницима Kodi-ја.</description>
        <description lang="sr_RS@latin">Estuary je podrazumevana maska za Kodi 17.0 i iznad. Pokušava da bude jednostavan za razumevanje i korišćenje novim korisnicima Kodija.</description>
        <description lang="sv_SE">Estuary är standardskalet för Kodi 17.0 och uppåt. Det är utformat för att vara lättförståeligt och användarvänligt för förstagångsanvändare av Kodi.</description>
        <description lang="szl">Estuary je wychodnōm skōrōm Kodi dlŏ wersyje 17.0 i dalszych. Prōbuje być proste dlŏ używŏczōw, dlŏ kerych Kodi je nowe</description>
        <description lang="th_TH">Estuary คือหน้าตาเริ่มต้นของ Kodi 17.0 และสูงกว่า เป็นความพยายามที่จะทำให้ง่ายสำหรับผู้ใช้ Kodi ในครั้งแรก ที่จะเข้าใจและใช้งาน</description>
        <description lang="tr_TR">Estuary Kodi 17.0 ve yukarısı için varsayılan dış görünümdür. İlk kez Kodi kullananlar için anlaşılması ve kullanımı kolaydır.</description>
        <description lang="uk_UA">Estuary є стандартною обкладинкою Kodi 17.0 і подальших версій. Її основна ідея — простота використання для нових користувачів Kodi.</description>
        <description lang="vi_VN">Estuary là giao diện mặc định cho Kodi 17.0 trở lên. Nó dễ dàng cho người dùng Kodi lần đầu tiên hiểu và sử dụng.</description>
        <description lang="zh_CN">Estuary 是 Kodi 17.0 的默认皮肤。它力求使首次使用 Kodi 的用户易于上手。</description>
        <description lang="zh_TW">Estuary是Kodi 17.0開始搭載的預設佈景主題。主要在讓第一次使用 Kodi 的使用者可以簡單地上手。</description>
        <disclaimer lang="af_ZA">Estuary is die bestek oortreksel vir Kodi, verwydering mag probleme veroorsaak</disclaimer>
        <disclaimer lang="ar_SA">Estuary هو المظهر الافتراضي ل كودي, إزالته قد تسبب بعض المشاكل</disclaimer>
        <disclaimer lang="be_BY">Estuary - прадвызначаная абалонка для Kodi. Яе выдаленне можа прывесці да праблем</disclaimer>
        <disclaimer lang="bg_BG">Estuary е стандартният облик на Kodi. Премахването му може да предизвика проблеми</disclaimer>
        <disclaimer lang="ca_ES">Estuary és l&apos;aparença predeterminada de Kodi, si s&apos;elimina pot causar problemes</disclaimer>
        <disclaimer lang="cs_CZ">Estuary je výchozí vzhled pro Kodi, jeho odebrání může způsobit problémy</disclaimer>
        <disclaimer lang="cy_GB">Estuary yw croen diofyn Kodi. Efallai bydd ei dynnu yn achosi problemau</disclaimer>
        <disclaimer lang="da_DK">Estuary er standard brugerfladen. Fjernes det kan der opstå problemer.</disclaimer>
        <disclaimer lang="de_DE">Estuary ist der Standardskin von Kodi. Ein Entfernen des Skins kann Probleme verursachen</disclaimer>
        <disclaimer lang="el_GR">Το Estuary είναι η προεπιλεγμένη αμφίεση για το Kodi. Η αφαίρεσή του μπορεί να δημιουργήσει προβλήματα.</disclaimer>
        <disclaimer lang="en_GB">Estuary is the default skin for Kodi, removing it may cause issues</disclaimer>
        <disclaimer lang="en_NZ">Estuary is the default skin for Kodi, removing it may cause issues</disclaimer>
        <disclaimer lang="en_US">Estuary is the default skin for Kodi, removing it may cause issues</disclaimer>
        <disclaimer lang="es_AR">Estuary es el skin por defecto de Kodi. Borrarlo puede causar problemas</disclaimer>
        <disclaimer lang="es_ES">Estuary es el skin por defecto de Kodi. Desinstalarlo puede causar problemas.</disclaimer>
        <disclaimer lang="es_MX">Estuary es la máscara predeterminada de Kodi, eliminarla puede causar problemas</disclaimer>
        <disclaimer lang="et_EE">Estuary on Kodi vaikerüü, selle eemaldamine võib põhjustada probleeme</disclaimer>
        <disclaimer lang="eu_ES">Estuary Kodiren azal lehenetsia da. Ezabatzeak arazoak eragin ditzake</disclaimer>
        <disclaimer lang="fa_IR">اسچوری پوستهٔ پیش‌گزیدهٔ کودی است. ممکن است برداشتنش موجب مشکلاتی شود</disclaimer>
        <disclaimer lang="fi_FI">Estuary on Kodin oletusulkoasu ja sen poisto voi aiheuttaa ongelmia</disclaimer>
        <disclaimer lang="fr_CA">Estuary est l’habillage par défaut de Kodi, le supprimer peut créer des problèmes</disclaimer>
        <disclaimer lang="fr_FR">Estuary est l&apos;habillage d&apos;origine de Kodi, le retirer peut créer des problèmes</disclaimer>
        <disclaimer lang="gl_ES">Estuary é a pel predefinida para Kodi e eliminala pode causar problemas.</disclaimer>
        <disclaimer lang="he_IL">Estuary היא מעטפת ברירת המחדל של קודי, הסרתה עלולה לגרום לתקלות</disclaimer>
        <disclaimer lang="hr_HR">Estuary je zadana presvlaka za Kodi, njegovo uklanjanje može uzrokovati poteškoće</disclaimer>
        <disclaimer lang="hu_HU">Az Estuary az alapértelmezett Kodi felszín. Eltávolítása problémákat okozhat</disclaimer>
        <disclaimer lang="id_ID">Estuary adalah skin default untuk Kodi, menghapusnya dapat menyebabkan masalah</disclaimer>
        <disclaimer lang="is_IS">Estuary er sjálfgefið skinn fyrir Kodi, ef það er fjarlægt gætu komið upp ýmis vandamál</disclaimer>
        <disclaimer lang="it_IT">Estuary è la skin predefinita di Kodi, rimuoverla potrebbe causare problemi</disclaimer>
        <disclaimer lang="ja_JP">EstuaryはKodiのデフォルトスキンなので、これを削除するとうまく動かなくなる可能性があります</disclaimer>
        <disclaimer lang="ko_KR">Estuary는 Kodi의 기본스킨으로 제거시 문제가 생길 수 있습니다</disclaimer>
        <disclaimer lang="lt_LT">Estuary yra numatytoji Kodi teminė išvaizda, jos pašalinimas gali sukelti problemų</disclaimer>
        <disclaimer lang="ms_MY">Estuary ialah kulit lalai Kodi, mengubahnya boleh menimbulkan isu.</disclaimer>
        <disclaimer lang="nb_NO">Estuary er forvalgt drakt for Kodi, dersom du fjerner det kan det forårsake problemer.</disclaimer>
        <disclaimer lang="nl_NL">Estuary is de standaardskin voor Kodi, het verwijderen van Estuary kan leiden tot problemen.</disclaimer>
        <disclaimer lang="pl_PL">Eustary jest domyślną skórą Kodi, usunięciejej może powodować problemy</disclaimer>
        <disclaimer lang="pt_BR">Estuary é a skin padrão para o Kodi, removendo-a pode causar problemas</disclaimer>
        <disclaimer lang="pt_PT">O Estuary é o visual por omissão do Kodi; se o remover, poderá ter alguns problemas</disclaimer>
        <disclaimer lang="ro_RO">Estuary este tema implicită pentru Kodi, eliminarea ei poate cauza probleme</disclaimer>
        <disclaimer lang="ru_RU">Estuary — это стандартная обложка Kodi, и ее удаление может привести к возникновению проблем</disclaimer>
        <disclaimer lang="sk_SK">Estuary je predvolený vzhľad pre Kodi, jeho odstránenie môže spôsobiť problémy</disclaimer>
        <disclaimer lang="sr_RS">Estuary је подразумевана маска за Kodi, уклањање може изазвати проблеме</disclaimer>
        <disclaimer lang="sr_RS@latin">Estuary je podrazumevana maska za Kodi, uklanjanje može izazvati probleme</disclaimer>
        <disclaimer lang="sv_SE">Estuary är Kodis standardskal. Om du tar bort det kan det orsaka problem.</disclaimer>
        <disclaimer lang="szl">Estuary je wychodnōm skōrōm Kodi, jij uchrōniynie może sprŏwiać niyprzileżytości</disclaimer>
        <disclaimer lang="th_TH">Estuary เป็นหน้าตาเริ่มต้นสำหรับ Kodi, การลบมัน อาจทำให้เกิดปัญหา</disclaimer>
        <disclaimer lang="tr_TR">Estuary Kodi için varsayılan dış görünümdür, kaldırmak sorunlara yol açabilir</disclaimer>
        <disclaimer lang="uk_UA">Estuary — основна обкладинка Kodi, і її видалення може призвести до проблем</disclaimer>
        <disclaimer lang="vi_VN">Estuary là giao diện mặc định cho Kodi, loại bỏ nó có thể gây ra sự cố</disclaimer>
        <disclaimer lang="zh_CN">Estuary 是 Kodi 的默认皮肤，删除它可能导致故障。</disclaimer>
        <disclaimer lang="zh_TW">Estuary 是 Kodi 預設的佈景主題，移除它可能會造成問題</disclaimer>
    </extension>
    
</addon>
```

then edit the Home.xml file to the content shown below and call the function to si:RunScript(script.scriptParaSkin, show)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<window>
    <defaultcontrol>9000</defaultcontrol>
    <backgroundcolor>white</backgroundcolor>
    <controls>
        
        <control type="image">
            <include file="ConstantesGlobales.xml"></include>
            <left>0</left>
            <top>0</top>
            <width>100%</width>
            <height>100%</height>
            <aspectratio>ESTIRAR_IMAGEN</aspectratio>
            <texture colordiffuse="00F0F0F0">fondo.png</texture>
        </control>

        <include content="foto">
            <param name="ancho" value="10%" />
            <param name="alto" value="50%" />
            <param name="src" value="defaultactorsolid.png" />
        </include>
        
        <include content="lista">
            <param name="XX" >300</param>
            <param name="YY" >10</param>

            <control type="image">
                <width>100</width>
                <height>100</height>
                <texture colordiffuse="CCF0F0F0">fondo.png</texture>
            </control>
            <control type="image">
                <top>101</top>
                <width>100</width>
                <height>100</height>
                <texture colordiffuse="CCF0F0F0">fondo.png</texture>
            </control>

        </include>

<control type="label" id="1">
        <description>My First label</description>
        <left>80</left>
        <top>60</top>
        <width>250</width>
        <visible>true</visible>
        <align>center</align>
        <aligny>center</aligny>
        <scroll>false</scroll>
        <label>$VAR[Example]</label>
        <angle>30</angle>
        <haspath>false</haspath>
        <font>font14</font>
        <textcolor>FFB2D4F5</textcolor>
        <shadowcolor>ff000000</shadowcolor>
        <wrapmultiline>false</wrapmultiline>
        <scrollspeed>50</scrollspeed>
        <scrollsuffix> - </scrollsuffix>
  </control>



<control type="button" id="1">
      <description>My first button control</description>
      <left>80</left>
      <top>60</top>
      <width>250</width>
      <height>200</height>
      <visible>true</visible>
      <colordiffuse>FFFFFFFF</colordiffuse>
      <texturefocus colordiffuse="FFFFAAFF">myfocustexture.png</texturefocus>
      <texturenofocus colordiffuse="FFFFAAFF">mynormaltexture.png</texturenofocus>
      <label>diferente</label>
      <wrapmultiline>true</wrapmultiline>
      <font>font12</font>
      <textcolor>FF000000</textcolor>
      <focusedcolor>FFFFFFFF</focusedcolor>
      <disabledcolor>80FFFFFF</disabledcolor>
      <invalidcolor>FFFFFFFF</invalidcolor>
      <align></align>
      <aligny></aligny>
      <textoffsetx></textoffsetx>
      <textoffsety></textoffsety>
      <pulseonselect></pulseonselect>
      <onclick>RunScript(script.scriptParaSkin, mostrar)</onclick>
      <onfocus></onfocus>
      <onunfocus></onunfocus>
      <onup>2</onup>
      <ondown>3</ondown>
      <onleft>1</onleft>
      <onright>1</onright>
</control>


    </controls>
</window>
```

then use this guide https://kodi.wiki/view/HOW-TO:Script_addon and the example they show for download as a base for my script where is the function I want to call edit the addon.xml file of that addon to this content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<addon id="script.scriptParaSkin" name="script skinivanjrch" version="1.0.0" provider-name="Ivan">
    <requires>
        <import addon="xbmc.python" version="3.0.0"/>
    </requires>
    <extension point="xbmc.python.script" library="script/scriptParaSkin.py">
        <provides>executable</provides>
    </extension>
    <extension point="xbmc.addon.metadata">
        <summary lang="en_GB">ivanjrch skin script</summary>
        <description lang="en_GB">ivanjrch skin script</description>
        <language></language>
        <platform>all</platform>
    </extension>
</addon>
```

then create a script folder and a file called scriptParaSkin.py and as content it has this:

```
import xbmcgui

def mostrar():
    xbmcgui.Dialog().notification("Hola", "¡Bienvenido a mi complemento para Kodi!")
```

Then I installed them both, but when I press the button nothing happens, what can I do? I have also tried to call it from the skin folder and nothing happens in the log that kodi launches, it does not show an error if I separate the skin and the script as I showed you and it installs fine, but nothing happens anyway, I need help, this is difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out what was going on, I didn't take into account that I was calling a file, so I removed the function definition, if you know a better way comment.

```
import xbmcgui

xbmcgui.Dialog().notification("Hola", "¡Bienvenido a mi complemento para Kodi!")
```

It also changes the way of calling the function, I no longer pass parameters to it.

```
<onclick>RunScript(script.scriptParaSkin)</onclick>
```